# yahoo finance volume to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, yahoo-finance

I have a list of shares and I want to loop through them to get today's volume using pdr.get_data_yahoo
this is my code

```
volist=[]
today = str(datetime.date.today())

for col in df.columns:#df.colomuns is the list of shares

    vol = pdr.get_data_yahoo(col,start=today,end=today)['Volume']
    volist.append(vol)
```

but I get error msg:
KeyError: 'Date'
I suspect some shares do not have volumes data available...
The secondary question :
also I want to compile a dataframe with share name (i.e"col") as index and volume as value like this:

```
share                  
BAP.AX         937459
CGC.AX         902398
NST.AX         876727
OML.AX         900462
ORA.AX         881516
```

how do I use loop to achieve this ?

Comment: I don’t think the issue is with your loop. As the error message states, the error is with the date in your parameter, possible “start”. What is the pdr class? Please provide the exception message too.

Comment: Hi the key error us just the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got to be bottom of it. Not every shares has price available for today. 
So use try and except to get around the issue:
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

```
import datetime 
main=pd.DataFrame()
today = str(datetime.date.today())

for col in df.columns:
    try:
        vol = pdr.get_data_yahoo(col,start=today,end=today)['Volume']



    except:
        pass
```